# Spring Integration - Using IntegrationManagementConfigurer with Service Activators

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to understand how to profile my Spring Integration application using the Metrics framework introduced in the Spring Integration 4.2 (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#mgmt-handler-features).

I can see how to use the framework to monitor Channels and Message Handlers (end points). How can I monitor beans that are annotated with `@ServiceActivator`?

```
for (String monitoredChannel : getMonitoredChannels()) {
    MessageChannelMetrics channelMetrics = integrationManagementConfigurer.getChannelMetrics(monitoredChannel);
    LOGGER.info("Channel {}, Send Count: {}", monitoredChannel, channelMetrics.getSendCount());
}

for (String monitoredHandler : getMonitoredHandlers()) {
    MessageHandlerMetrics handlerMetrics = integrationManagementConfigurer.getHandlerMetrics(monitoredHandler);
    LOGGER.info("Handler {}, Max Duration: {}", monitoredHandler, handlerMetrics.getDuration().getMax());
    LOGGER.info("Handler {}, Min Duration: {}", monitoredHandler, handlerMetrics.getDuration().getMin());
    LOGGER.info("Handler {}, Mean Duration: {}", monitoredHandler, handlerMetrics.getMeanDuration());
}
```

Is there a similar way to monitor named Service Activators? This what my integration-context.xml looks like:

```
<int:chain input-channel="messageReceived" output-channel="messageValidated" id="messageValidationChain">
    <int:service-activator ref="enricher" method="getMessageAttributes" id="attributeEnricher" />
    <int:service-activator ref="stateValidator" method="processMessage" id="stateValidator" />
    <int:service-activator ref="attributeValidator" method="validateMessage" id="attributeValidator"/>  
</int:chain>
```

I want to be able to profile how long each `ServiceActivator`in a processing chain takes and keep track of metrics such as min, max, mean duration, message counts etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just works.

The bean names for the service activator message handlers in the chain are

```
<chainId>.<elementId>.handler
```

Comment: Thank you Gary. Since I am using a chain instead of an explicit channel, I found that the ServiceActivator beans were defined as children of the parent chain. I.e., the beans could be addressed by: <chainId>$child.<elementId>.handler. In the example above, I was able to get the MessageHandlerMetrics bean by referring to messageValidationChain$child.attributeEnricher.handler.